# Using AVX CPU instructions: Poor performance without "/arch:AVX"

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010, sse, avx

My C++ code uses SSE and now I want to improve it to support AVX when it is available. So I detect when AVX is available and call a function that uses AVX commands. I use Win7 SP1 + VS2010 SP1 and a CPU with AVX.

To use AVX, it is necessary to include this:

```
#include "immintrin.h"
```

and then you can use intrinsics AVX functions like `_mm256_mul_ps`, `_mm256_add_ps` etc.
The problem is that by default, VS2010 produces code that works very slowly and shows the warning:

> warning C4752: found Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions; consider
>   using /arch:AVX

It seems VS2010 actually does not use AVX instructions, but instead, emulates them. I added `/arch:AVX` to the compiler options and got good results. But this option tells the compiler to use AVX commands everywhere when possible. So my code may crash on CPU that does not support AVX!

So the question is how to make VS2010 compiler to produce AVX code but only when I specify AVX intrinsics directly. For SSE it works, I just use SSE intrinsics functions and it produce SSE code without any compiler options like `/arch:SSE`. But for AVX it does not work for some reason.

Comment: In my question I specified that my CPU supports AVX. Actually I has several systems, some with AVX and some without so I see what happens when AVX is not supported.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

2021 update: Modern versions of MSVC don't need manual use of `_mm256_zeroupper()` even when compiling AVX intrinsics without `/arch:AVX`.  VS2010 did.

---

The behavior that you are seeing is the result of expensive state-switching.

See page 102 of Agner Fog's manual:

http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf

Every time you improperly switch back and forth between SSE and AVX instructions, you will pay an extremely high (~70) cycle penalty.

When you compile without `/arch:AVX`, VS2010 will generate SSE instructions, but will still use AVX wherever you have AVX intrinsics. Therefore, you'll get code that has both SSE and AVX instructions - which will have those state-switching penalties. (VS2010 knows this, so it emits that warning you're seeing.)

Therefore, you should use either all SSE, or all AVX. Specifying `/arch:AVX` tells the compiler to use all AVX.

It sounds like you're trying to make multiple code paths: one for SSE, and one for AVX.
For this, I suggest you separate your SSE and AVX code into two different compilation units. (one compiled with `/arch:AVX` and one without) Then link them together and make a dispatcher to choose based on the what hardware it's running on.

If you ***need*** to mix SSE and AVX, be sure to use `_mm256_zeroupper()` or `_mm256_zeroall()` appropriately to avoid the state-switching penalties.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Currently I use both SSE and AVX. So compiler always produces AVX code (even w/o /arch:AVX), I've just checked it with disassembly dbg window.  Now I will improve my AVX code to use AVX only. Thank you!!!

Comment: **Update:** Agner Fog's manual seems to have been updated since I posted this answer. The relevant section is now on page 103, section 8.12.

Comment: What does it mean to mix? If I use both _mm_load_ps and _mm256_load_px, is it considered a mix?

Comment: @Ben-Uri When AVX was added, they added a new VEX encoding scheme for all AVX instructions. Furthermore, all SSE instructions were given VEX-encoded equivalents. By "mixing", I'm referring to the use of both legacy-encoded and VEX-encoded instructions in close proximity. When you compile with `/arch:AVX`, it forces the compiler to use all VEX-encoding - even for SSE instructions/intrinsics. So to answer your question, using both `_mm_load_ps` and `_mm256_load_ps` will not "mix" if you have `/arch:AVX` enabled. But they *will* mix if you don't.

Comment: See also **[Intel's nice diagram of state transitions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-avx-state-transitions-migrating-sse-code-to-avx)**, which makes it clear that mixing SSE and AVX-128 is fine, as long as you did a `vzeroupper` since the last AVX-256 instruction.  (I'm not sure if OS context switches ever leave you in state B, though, in which case mixing AVX-128 and SSE-128 isn't safe).

Comment: @PeterCordes If AVX (and VEX) is available, why not to use it? You get  three-operand instructions (leading to less moves) and you don't have to bother with state switching and things like `vzeroupper`.

Comment: @plasmacel: The only reason I can think of to do it on purpose would be code-size.  `MOVAPS [rdi], xmm0` is 3 bytes.  `VMOVAPS [rdi], xmm0` is 4 bytes.  But there's also calls to library functions that might use SSE: you don't need VZEROUPPER before / after using AVX-128.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's worth noting that the upcoming SHA instructions won't have VEX-prefixed versions. But the state-transition penalties have gone away in Skylake and presumably future processors as well.

Comment: @Mysticial: VZEROUPPER is still recommended for SKL [to avoid penalties on a per-register basis](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#477).  It's not clear if that's like a false-dependency, or if it takes extra time to dig the saved bits out of storage or something.

Comment: It looks like Andy Polyakov calls `vzeroupper` when entering and exiting an AVX function. Also see [OpenSSL | chacha-x86_64.pl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/chacha/asm/chacha-x86_64.pl). (chacha-x86_64.pl is the template file that gets transformed to the *.S file for assembling).

Comment: @plasmacel: with the benefit of more wisdom: the reason old MSVC creates SSE/AVX transition penalties is that it doesn't optimize intrinsics.  At least with older MSVC, you had to use `/arch:AVX` to get non-stupid code-gen for functions that use 256-bit intrinsics.  I think the idea is that you might only done that inside an `if(cpu_has_avx)` branch, and it must avoid running VEX instructions on code paths where they weren't definitely asked for.  (With AVX-only intrinsics or with command line options).  I think newer MSVC is less dumb and stops you from naively shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 24):

**tl;dr for old versions of MSVC only**

Use [`_mm256_zeroupper();`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514196) or [`_mm256_zeroall();`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514195) around sections of code using AVX (before or after depending on function arguments). Only use option `/arch:AVX` for source files with AVX rather than for an entire project to avoid breaking support for legacy-encoded SSE-only code paths.

In modern MSVC (and the other mainstream compilers, GCC/clang/ICC), **the compiler knows when to use a `vzeroupper` asm instruction.**  Forcing extra `vzeroupper`s with intrinsics can hurt performance when inlining.  See **[Do I need to use _mm256_zeroupper in 2021?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736527/do-i-need-to-use-mm256-zeroupper-in-2021)**

**Cause**

I think the best explanation is in the Intel article, ["Avoiding AVX-SSE Transition Penalties"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-avx-sse-transition-penalties) ([PDF](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/11MC12_Avoiding_2BAVX-SSE_2BTransition_2BPenalties_2Brh_2Bfinal.pdf)). The abstract states:

> Transitioning between 256-bit Intel® AVX instructions and legacy Intel® SSE instructions within a program may cause performance penalties because the hardware must save and restore the upper 128 bits of the YMM registers.

Separating your AVX and SSE code into different compilation units **may NOT help** if you switch between calling code from both SSE-enabled and AVX-enabled object files, because the transition may occur when AVX instructions or assembly are mixed with any of (from the Intel paper):

- 128-bit intrinsic instructions
- SSE inline assembly
- C/C++ floating point code that is compiled to Intel® SSE
- **Calls to functions or libraries that include any of the above**

This means there may even be penalties when linking with *external code* using SSE.

**Details**

There are 3 processor states defined by the AVX instructions, and one of the states is where all of the [YMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions) registers are split, allowing the lower half to be used by [SSE instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions).  The Intel document "[Intel® AVX State Transitions: Migrating SSE Code to AVX](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-avx-state-transitions-migrating-sse-code-to-avx)" provides a diagram of these states:

[image]

When in state B (AVX-256 mode), all bits of the YMM registers are in use.  When an SSE instruction is called, a transition to state C must occur, and this is where there is a penalty.  The upper half of all YMM registers must be saved into an internal buffer before SSE can start, even if they happen to be zeros.  The cost of the transitions is on the "order of 50-80 clock cycles on Sandy Bridge hardware".  There is also a penalty going from C -> A, as diagrammed in Figure 2.

You can also find details about the state switching penalty causing this slowdown on page 130, Section 9.12, "Transitions between [VEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEX_prefix) and non-VEX modes" in [Agner Fog's optimization guide](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) (of version updated 2014-08-07), referenced in [Mystical's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841251/2778484). According to his guide, any transition to/from this state takes "about 70 clock cycles on Sandy Bridge". Just as the Intel document states, this is an avoidable transition penalty.

Skylake has a different dirty-upper mechanism that causes false dependencies for legacy-SSE with dirty uppers, rather than one-time penalties.  [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake)

**Resolution**

To avoid the transition penalties you can either remove all legacy SSE code, instruct the compiler to convert all SSE instructions to their VEX encoded form of 128-bit instructions (if compiler is capable), or put the YMM registers in a known zero state before transitioning between AVX and SSE code. Essentially, to maintain the separate SSE code path, you must **zero out the upper 128-bits of all 16 YMM registers (issuing a `VZEROUPPER` instruction) after any code that uses AVX instructions**.  Zeroing these bits manually forces a transition to state A, and avoids the expensive penalty since the YMM values do not need to be stored in an internal buffer by hardware. The intrinsic that performs this instruction is [`_mm256_zeroupper`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514196).  The description for this intrinsic is very informative:

> This intrinsic is useful to clear the upper bits of the YMM registers when transitioning between Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel® AVX) instructions and legacy Intel® Supplemental SIMD Extensions (Intel® SSE) instructions. There is **no transition penalty if an application clears the upper bits of all YMM registers** (sets to ‘0’) via `VZEROUPPER`, the corresponding instruction for this intrinsic, before transitioning between Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel® AVX) instructions and legacy Intel® Supplemental SIMD Extensions (Intel® SSE) instructions.

In Visual Studio 2010+ (maybe even older), [you get this intrinsic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977023(v=vs.110).aspx) with immintrin.h.

Note that zeroing out the bits with other methods does not eliminate the penalty - the `VZEROUPPER` or `VZEROALL` instructions must be used.

One automatic solution implemented by the Intel Compiler is to insert a `VZEROUPPER` **at the beginning** of each function containing Intel AVX code if none of the arguments are a YMM register or `__m256`/`__m256d`/`__m256i` datatype, and **at the end** of functions if the returned value is not a YMM register or `__m256`/`__m256d`/`__m256i` datatype.

**In the wild**

This `VZEROUPPER` solution is used by FFTW to generate a library with both SSE and AVX support.  See [simd-avx.h](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/c69d6c3c7512a814efe229d15e51dda0c1590ee6/simd-support/simd-avx.h#L402):

```
/* Use VZEROUPPER to avoid the penalty of switching from AVX to SSE.
   See Intel Optimization Manual (April 2011, version 248966), Section
   11.3 */
#define VLEAVE _mm256_zeroupper
```

Then `VLEAVE();` is called at the end of *every* function using intrinsics for AVX instructions.