# Enable AVX instructions with mex using gcc 4.6.1

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization, gcc, avx

I'd like to mess around with some AVX intrinsic functions. I'd like gcc to use AVX exclusively if possible similar to `/arch:AVX` in visual studio. Is there a way to do this in gcc with mex?

I tried using something like:

`mex -g -O $CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -march=corei7-avx' ncorr_alg_rgdic.cpp standard_datatypes.o ncorr_datatypes.o`

But the compiler says `eval: 1: = -march=corei7-avx: not found`. Does anyone know which flag I should use and how to get mex to accept it? By default it seems to be using SSE instructions (looking at the assembly output I see some `mulsd`s) but I don't want to mix SSE with AVX as I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839925/using-avx-cpu-instructions-poor-performance-without-archavx/7841251#7841251) that it can cause problems.

**EDIT1:**

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 with gcc 4.6.1.

**EDIT2:**

Compiling with:
`mex CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-mtune=corei7-avx -S' ncorr_alg_rgdic.cpp standard_datatypes.o ncorr_datatypes.o`

Yields:

```
movsd   -304(%rbp), %xmm1
movsd   .LC16(%rip), %xmm0
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
```

Compiling with:
`mex CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-mavx -S' ncorr_alg_rgdic.cpp standard_datatypes.o ncorr_datatypes.o` 
and `mex CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-march=corei7-avx -S' ncorr_alg_rgdic.cpp standard_datatypes.o ncorr_datatypes.o` 
Both yield:

```
vmovsd  -304(%rbp), %xmm1
vmovsd  .LC16(%rip), %xmm0
vmulsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm1
```

Now I'm pretty sure `mulsd` is an sse instruction. Is `vmulsd` an AVX instruction (strangely googling it didn't yield any results)? I also don't see an `ymm` registers being used which is strange.

Comment: It should be just `-mavx`.

Comment: @Mysticial If I use `$CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -mavx'`, the matlab terminal says `eval: 1: = -mavx: not found`... This may be because I'm not passing the compiler flag properly to mex.

Comment: What platform are you targeting? On Windows, `CFLAGS` should be replaced with `COMPFLAGS`. Also, the `-g` option disables optimizations, and as such is not compatible with the `-O` option. GCC may not emit AVX instructions unless you're compiling with a minimum level of optimizations enabled. Remove `-g`, and add `-v` to get mex to print out the compiler invocation command line. Look through that make sure the appropriate optimization level is enabled.

Comment: @Praetorian I was keeping the `-g` flag because the way I had been viewing assembly (to unsure AVX instructions are being used) was by using gdb. Is `-O` really not compatible with `-g`? If I used both the file runs at about `-O` speeds but also allows me to debug it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it doesn't. The documentation is confusing. `-g` description: *Create ... additional symbolic information for use in debugging. This option disables the mex default behavior of optimizing built object code*. `-O` description: *Optimize the object code. ... If the -g option appears without the -O option, optimization is disabled.* You should be able to view assembly by passing the `-S` switch to GCC (once you figure out your CFLAGS problem :-))

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for the `-S` switch. Did not know about this!! I also added some stuff to my post in edit2.

Comment: @Mysticial I used `-mavx` and it resulted in a `vmulsd` instruction instead of a `mulsd`. Would you happen to know why no `ymm` registers appear to be used?

Comment: @jucestain Yes. That's normal. There's no need to use the full `ymm` registers when you're only doing scalar operations.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks, I think the way the code is written now it'll be hard for the compiler to identify vector operations. I'm going to experiment with some intrinsics just as a learning experience to see if I can get any results. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yeah, I usually don't rely on compiler vectorization at all. It fails on all the complicated cases, and the simple cases are rarely performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Mysticial Interesting. Very excited to try this stuff out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I've found is that mex uses this format:

> mex -v CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -Wall' LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS -w' yprime.c

you should try and remove the first $ sign. -mtune=corei7-avx should be right, though.

Comment: +1 This solved part of the problem. I just need to figure out now if AVX instructions are actually being used now.

Comment: it probably does. according to wikipedia AVX introduces a 3-operand form of instructions (vmulsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm1). the new AVX registers ymmX are simply an extension to xmmX from 128 to 256 bits. if your code doesn't need that much precision the compiler doesn't care. btw: could it be, that after your 2nd edit some other optimizations were removed? (like -O3)

Comment: It appears that if I use `CXXOPTIMFLAGS='$CXXOPTIMFLAGS'`, it deletes the `-O` compiler flag. My understanding is that the `$CXXOPTIMFLAGS` is supposed to append flags which are already defined in `CXXOPTIMAFLAGS` which is `-O -DNDEBUG`.

Comment: Just as a final note, I realized through the `mex` documentation that you need to do `mex CXXOPTIMFLAGS="\$CXXOPTIMFLAGS -mavx" ncorr_alg_rgdic.cpp standard_datatypes.o ncorr_datatypes.o`. The backslash and `"` is required in order to append `-mavx` to the default settings when compiling the `mex` file through the matlab terminal.