# How to load 128bit data to ymm register in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, avx, avx2

I want to load 128bit data to ymm register.
I need 256bit data like this in ymm register.

```
0000000000000000-0000000000000000-08AE038400570064-0005000A1E810BB8
```

So I did like below;

```
vmovdqa ymm0, xmmword ptr[eax]
```

But I got build error.
How can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Just use `xmm0` instead.

Comment: Do you mean vmovdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr[eax]? But I just want to use ymm register, I need to use data like 0000-0000-xxxx-xxxx(256bit).

Comment: That is what you will get. Did you try it? Did you consult the instruction set reference?

Comment: I tried to find correct mov instruction, but I couldn't find correct one. I could load 64bit data to xmm register(like 0000000000000000-08AE038400570064). vmovsd xmm0, real8 ptr[ebp+8]. But I failed to use ymm registers.

Comment: `vmovdqa xmm0, [eax]` does implicitly zero-extend into YMM0, unlike `movdqa xmm0, [eax]`.  Note the `DEST[MAXVL-1:128] := 0` in the pseudo-code for that form: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdqa:vmovdqa32:vmovdqa64#vmovdqa--vex-128-encoded-version-  The next section with `DEST[MAXVL-1:128] (Unmodified)` is incorrectly labeled "VMOVDQA legacy SSE version", the legacy SSE form doesn't have a V in the mnemonic.  Also related: [Why do SSE instructions preserve the upper 128-bit of the YMM registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41819514)

Comment: You do know `xmm0` is the same register as `ymm0`, right?

Comment: @Jester, xmm is 128bit register, ymm is 256bit register, right?

Comment: xmm is the low 128 bits of the corresponding ymm. It's the same register.

Comment: @Jester, Thank you for your kind explains, I am now clear about xmm and ymm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did resolve like this;

```
vmovdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr[eax]
```

So if I debug, I could see xmm,ymm registers like this.

```
XMM0 = 0457FCEF00EAFC74-62CC03110038001E
... ...
YMM0 = 0000000000000000-0000000000000000-0457FCEF00EAFC74-62CC03110038001E
```

So, this is that I want.
Thanks for your helps.